# Selenium-Server: Weird message when using browserReuseSession flag

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I get the error message:

```
sel_<NUMBER> resultHolder sel_<NUMBER> unexpected response: OK,..
```

It seems that the server is stuck after this message occurs.

Why is this happening and how to solve/prevent it? I've never seen this message when the `browserReuseSession` is off. Have you?

Comment: What appears to be causing this error message? Is it a certain command, or just starting the server? What version of Selenium RC are you using, and on what OS?

Comment: It doesn't seem like a specific command. It happens on and off after many commands took place. The OS I'm running on is XP and the selenium server version is 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The theory is that selenium uses /dev/random and that /dev/random blocks when the entropy pool gets low.  When this happens, selenium is also blocked.

I am trying the following workaround on my Macbook:

sudo mv /dev/random /dev/random.real

sudo ln -s /dev/urandom /dev/random

Wish me luck.  :)

Comment: Nope.  Took a few hours but it occurred.  Rats!

Comment: Latest theory is that the problem is the small default size of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).  I turned on all the logging and the problem occurred almost instantly. "xmlHttp returned: 500: Internal Server Error" followed immediately by complaints about lack of JVM resources.  So I added "-Xmx2g" (i.e. java -Xmx2g -jar selenium_server ...) to increase the maximum size from (probably) 256MB to 2GB.  Lets see how it goes.....